# unable to convert numpy array to tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm, tensor

**I'm trying to make a model that predicts a label based off an embedded sentence. Whenever I try to train my model on x and y values an error shows:

```
---> 67 model.fit(x, y, epochs=100)
ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type list).
```

here is my code:
**

```
file = pd.read_csv('emoji.csv') 
emoji_mapping = {0:':red_heart:',1: ':baseball:',2: ':grinning_face_with_big_eyes:',3: ':disappointed_face:',4: ':fork_and_knife_with_plate:'} 
def emojize(r): 
return emoji.emojize(emoji_mapping.get(r))
x = np.array(file['French macaroon is so tasty']) 
y = np.array(file['4']) 
for i,v in enumerate(y): 
if v == '0v2':
y = list(y) 
x = list(x)
y.remove(v) 
x.remove(x[i]) 
y = np.array(y) 
x=np.array(x)    
vector_mapping = {}
glove_100d = open('glove.6B.100d.csv','r',encoding = 'utf8') 
for line in glove_100d: 
line = line.split() 
word = line[0] 
vector = np.array(line[1:],dtype = str)
vector_mapping[word] = vector  
glove_100d.close() 
keys = list(vector_mapping.keys())
x = [i.split(' ') for i in x]  

for i,v in enumerate(x): 
for m,r in enumerate(v):  
if r in keys:
x[i][m] = vector_mapping.get(r) 
else: 
x[i][m] = vector_mapping.get('the') 
for i,v in enumerate(x):   
v = [float(num) for sublist in v for num in sublist] 
x[i] = v     
model = Sequential()  
model.add(LSTM(units = 20,return_sequences = True)) 
model.add(Dense(units = 5,activation = 'softmax')) 
model.compile(optimizer = 'adam',loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy')  
x = x[:180] 
y = y[:180]  
y = [int(i) for i in y] 

x = np.reshape(x, (np.shape(x)[0], 1, 1))
y = np.reshape(y,(len(y),1))  
x = np.array(x)
y = np.array(y)

model.fit(x,y,epochs = 100)
```

I haven't tried padding the x arrays so that they are all of the same length.

Comment: Fix the indentation.

Comment: Try to avoid list->array->list. Data cleaning with your original pandas dataframe should be easier/more compact

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM, Dense

```
file = pd.read_csv('emoji.csv')
emoji_mapping = {0: ':red_heart:', 1: ':baseball:', 2: ':grinning_face_with_big_eyes:', 3: ':disappointed_face:', 4: ':fork_and_knife_with_plate:'}

def emojize(r):
    return emoji.emojize(emoji_mapping.get(r))

x = np.array(file['French macaroon is so tasty'])
y = np.array(file['4'])

for i, v in enumerate(y):
    if v == '0v2':
        y = list(y)
        x = list(x)
        y.remove(v)
        x.remove(x[i])

y = np.array(y)
x = np.array(x)

vector_mapping = {}
glove_100d = open('glove.6B.100d.csv', 'r', encoding='utf8')

for line in glove_100d:
    line = line.split()
    word = line[0]
    vector = np.array(line[1:], dtype=str)
    vector_mapping[word] = vector

glove_100d.close()

keys = list(vector_mapping.keys())
x = [i.split(' ') for i in x]

for i, v in enumerate(x):
    for m, r in enumerate(v):
        if r in keys:
            x[i][m] = vector_mapping.get(r)
        else:
            x[i][m] = vector_mapping.get('the')

for i, v in enumerate(x):
    v = [float(num) for sublist in v for num in sublist]
    x[i] = v

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(units=20, return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dense(units=5, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy')

x = x[:180]
y = y[:180]
y = [int(i) for i in y]

x = np.reshape(x, (np.shape(x)[0], 1, 1))
y = np.reshape(y, (len(y), 1))
x = np.array(x)
y = np.array(y)

model.fit(x, y, epochs=100)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).